# How to use wkHtmltoPdf to generate PDf files from statcic html files in C#

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

Can anyone suggest how to use wkhtmltopdf in C# Console application to generate PDF files from static html files?

wkhtmltopdf  -  http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

I have tried downloading the ibwkhtmltox-0.11.0_rc1 Windows Static Library (i368) 
but cant include its dll into my c# console app.

Any code samples will be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can I would suggest using the exe - I think it's simpler.

For an example, check out the [Derp class in another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292689/wkhtmltopdf-outputstream-download-diaglog/11991670#11991670) regarding how to run the wkhtmltopdf exe from C#. Or try something like the **untested** code below (your true code will be more complicated, this is just a demo/POC). Just replace google.com with the HTML page you want - you can use local files as well.

```
var pi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe");
pi.CreateNoWindow = true;
pi.UseShellExecute = false;
pi.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\wkhtmltopdf\";
pi.Arguments = "http://www.google.com gogl.pdf";

using (var process = Process.Start(pi))
{
    process.WaitForExit(99999);
    Debug.WriteLine(process.ExitCode);
}
```

(answer repeated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992062/694325)

Comment: Why -1? I understand that this might not be good for every solution for every case, but a comment would be nice :X.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this project [github.com/gmanny/Pechkin](http://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin), it is a wrapper around wkhtmlpdf, but because it doesn't run as an executable, you should have an easier time getting it to run it on a shared host.

Comment: please do not post single link

Answer (score 3):

I'm mid implementation using WkHtmlToPdf via Pechkin's C# port - so far I'm seeing some great results (except a rather strange issue when calling a dynamically generated PDF from a site using SSL) however for more basic implementations it is great! Use NuGet to get Pechkin into your project then use the following code!

```
byte[] pdf = new Pechkin.Synchronized.SynchronizedPechkin(
new Pechkin.GlobalConfig()).Convert(
    new Pechkin.ObjectConfig()
   .SetLoadImages(true)
   .SetPrintBackground(true)
   .SetScreenMediaType(true)
   .SetCreateExternalLinks(true), html);

using (FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\TEMP\Output.pdf"))
{
    file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.......... Try once.

```
   protected static byte[] Convert(string wkhtmlPath, string switches, string html, string wkhtmlExe)
    {       
        // generate PDF from given HTML string, not from URL
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
        {               
            html = SpecialCharsEncode(html);
        }

        var proc = new Process();

        var StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        proc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(wkhtmlPath, wkhtmlExe);
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = switches;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = wkhtmlPath;

        proc.Start();

        // generate PDF from given HTML string, not from URL
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))
        {
            using (var sIn = proc.StandardInput)
            {
                sIn.WriteLine(html);
            }
        }

        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        using (var sOut = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream)
        {                              
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int read;

            while ((read = sOut.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }

        string error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        if (ms.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception(error);
        }

        proc.WaitForExit();

        return ms.ToString(); 
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Encode all special chars
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">Html text</param>
    /// <returns>Html with special chars encoded</returns>
    private static string SpecialCharsEncode(string text)
    {
        var chars = text.ToCharArray();
        var result = new StringBuilder(text.Length + (int)(text.Length * 0.1));

        foreach (var c in chars)
        {
            var value = System.Convert.ToInt32(c);
            if (value > 127)
                result.AppendFormat("&#{0};", value);
            else
                result.Append(c);
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }


}
```

Here we return memory stream, we further need to add header, content type

```
   public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
       // this.FileName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

        var fileContent =  Convert(wkhtmltopdfPath, switches, null, wkhtmlExe);

        var response = this.PrepareResponse(context.HttpContext.Response);

        response.OutputStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
    }

    protected HttpResponseBase PrepareResponse(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        response.ContentType = this.GetContentType();
        this.FileName = "YourFile.pdf";
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FileName))
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", SanitizeFileName(this.FileName)));
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", this.GetContentType());

        return response;
    }
```